# PHP PDO DbLib - SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server connection failed (severity 9)

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

in my PHP application I am suing PDO DbLib driver to connect to Microsoft SQL Server database and sometimes I am getting this PDO Exception:

> SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server connection failed (severity 9)

The weird thing is, that I am not getting this exception always, only sometimes. Sometimes I get that exception once per 10 executions, sometimes once per 50 executions of the application.

This is the database class constructor, which is initialising database connection:

```
function __construct($SQLHOST, $SQLPORT, $SQLDB, $SQLUSER, $SQLPWD, $SQLDRIVER)
{
    try {
        $pdo_connect = "dblib:version=8.0;host=" . $SQLHOST . ":" . $SQLPORT . ";dbname=" . $SQLDB . ";";
        $this->db = new PDO($pdo_connect, $SQLUSER, $SQLPWD);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->dead = true;
        $this->error = "PDOException: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?